# Moving links in jQuery, adding to string causes [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to move a link around but when I try to include it within a string it doesn't work. If I remove the string it does though. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var link = $('a');

    //Remove the '<div>'s and it works...
    $('div').after('<div>'+link+'</div>'); 
});
```

See pen for an example: http://cdpn.io/AKnsL

Thanks.

ED: I probably should of noted that this is a simplified version of what I am trying to do, I'm trying to rebuild a menu (don't ask why...) and I have each link assigned to a variable which is then added in place to a rather long string of divs and such, which is all then added in "after" another div. I only mention in case it changes the way this could be done, and I should mention I'm no JS pro :)

Thanks#2!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("a")` is actually an object, not a string. If you use `$("div").after(link)`, jQuery will work out that you actually want to append the DOM element.

The problem comes in when you do `'<div>' + link + '</div>'`, where JavaScript is creating the string *before* jQuery gets involved. this is where `[object Object]` comes from - this is JavaScript's way of creating a sensible String value for an object. What's being evaluated is `$("div").after("<div>[object Object]</div>");`

You can get around this by first creating your new `div`, appending the `a` to that, then appending your new div to the original.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var link = $("a"),
      new_div = $("<div />").append(link);

  $("div").after(new_div);
});
```

Comment: This makes sense, and using the method you provided I figured it out :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because a jQuery selector, such as `$('a')` returns an object, and appending a string and an object results in what you've seen.

If you want to move the link to a different element in the DOM, use `append()`:

```
var link = $('a');
$('div').append(link);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$('div').after('<div/>',{html:link});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
div.innerHTML=""+$('a').attr("href").toString()+"";
```

or:

```
var str="";
str+=""+$('a').attr("href").toString()+""; // str will contain links href in it
```

That will append text to div as a string with its `href` as text to be appended.